# How can I build someone else's Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I was given a project folder which contains an Xcode project along with all the source files. When I open the Xcode project, and build it, it gave me this error:

> "The executable was signed with
>   invalid entitlements"

How can I change the project such that my own provisioning profile will work? It should be possible because I have opened Xcode projects before and was able to build it straight to my phone.

Edit:

1. Code signing entitlements is blank
2. This is not an ad-hoc build. It is debug and I am copy/pasting someone else's folder which contains the Xcode project and files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that sign identity, entitlements, etc. is properly set for both the Project and the Target. Preferably delete the setting for the Target and only define for the Project.

Comment: Thx PeyloW. Any instructions on that? In build, for Code Signing identity, I have iPhone Developer. Code Signing entitlements is blank.

Comment: Yko - That should be enough. If it still don't work clean all targets, and build again.

Comment: Thanks PeyloW. A simple clean all target is needed. Would be interesting to know why but definitely not needed.

Comment: @Yko - Xcode will only re-sign the application if it needs to be rebuild, and it is only rebuilt if you have modified the code. Modifying setting does not count, I consider this a bug and have filed a report at http://bugreport.apple.com before, you should to if you want this issue to get priority.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test in the simulator, go the the project and press 'delete' on the **code sign identity** and **entitlements** so they will be cleared. Please note: you won't be able to test on device like this, an identity is required to test on devices.

If you want to test on device as well, change the code sign identity to your own identity and make sure the identifier in the project's .plist is set to your company (the company identifier needs to match the code sign identity's identifier). Generally people use the *reverse domain identifier*, e.g. com.mycompany.myproject.